# Affine space in classical mechanics and it's applicability in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, metric-tensor, space-expansion, galilean-relativity

In the first chapter of Arnold book of Classical Mechanics while giving Galilean structure of spacetime we're introduced to affine space. As already mentioned in answers to this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/568847/vector-space-vs-affine-space-in-lagrangian-mechanics) this is done "*to make all points equal*".

There is a very similar situation in FRW metric of GR: the space is three-dimensional Euclidean at an instant of time and it's homogenous and isotropic. So why we're introduced to FRW metric affine structure is not mentioned? Is it due to $a(t)$ that the affine nature of $t$ coordinate is lost?